# Get rid of <select> highlight in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select

Trying to get rid of the blue highlight in IE. This is a select tag. When you pull down the dropbox and choose an option, the blue highlight appears. I am on a Mac and do not have IE so I cannot test it. Is it just background-color: transparent?

Here is an image of what I am seeing. http://postimg.org/image/xa8kmxfbt/

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
select::-ms-value {background: transparent;}
```

This will change its colour once selected, but while selecting, you'll still see that blue colour on hover.

Comment: The text is white after being selected though. It only changes back to the normal color of text if you remove focus. Do you know if there's any way to fix that?

Comment: adding `color: black;` seems to fix that

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to blur the `select`. Simple example:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="this.blur();">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>baz</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kJNX3/